# TeeChart v2015 Pro Evaluation: TeeCommander useless for non 3D charts

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-10-seattle

Newer versions of TeeChart have TeeCommander component - toolbar for performing some actions. But it always sets the chart to be 3D before performing any scrolling or zooming.

To re-produce, either see Toolbar demo (if you load examples\features\Tee9New - just choose to continue after all exceptions) and set the chart to be 3D using the editor button on the toolbar or create a new VCL forms application, drop TChart and TTeeCommander components and set teeComander1.panel to be Chart1.

Is there a way to:

- Prevent scroll/zoom buttons to switch 3D to TRUE?
- Disable/Hide some buttons (Rotate)

similar as TDBNavigator?

Comment: Regarding the errors you get with the Tee9New demo, have you reported them? I can navigate to the Toolbar example without seeing any error here.

Comment: Note the TeeCommander component has been there since at least TeeChart VCL v5. So not only newer versions include this component.

Comment: Yeray, I will check whether I can report - I have TeeChart 7.5 and I am in process of evaluation of Ver2015. To reproduce the errors in Tee9New demo go to search, type Tool in CBSearch and press SearchButton. The first exception was in tools_clustering.pas - the lines in IrisDataSet. are broken: '5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa'#$D#$A'6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-'#$D#$A'versicolor'#$D#$A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you noticed is actually happening since at least TeeChart VCL v6. So it could be a limitation per design.

I found an old ticket reporting it so I've moved it to the public tracker:
http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1350

Thanks for reporting it.

A simple workaround would be setting a very little `Chart3DPercent` so that features can work and the 3D will be almost unnoticeable:

```
Chart1.Chart3DPercent:=1;
```

> Disable/Hide some buttons (Rotate)

See the "Custom buttons" example at the Features Demo under the "All features\Welcome !\Toolbar" section.

Comment: Yeray, thank you for for the workaround and the hint